# Multiple Entries - Count Value in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Thanks, friends, for the help and feedback. I know i am not good with PHP but still trying to learn and playing with it :D -- My table contains duplicate entries against evaid as Open Close or In Process --- with below code I get the last entered status from DB against each status by using query and if statement to show the data but i want to get the count of it as well. Anyone can help me out --- For example ---

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM disagreements ORDER BY addeddate DESC) disagreements  GROUP BY evaid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {   // Here with this query I got last entered status of each row against evaid – as 2 Open – 5 in Process and 10 Closed --- with below if statement – I can echo the rows with status but I want to have count of it that how many are open, in process or closed
        if($row["status"]=='Open') {  // I want to count this value as 2        
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["evaid"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["status"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } 
    }

} else {
    echo "Nothing to Display";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: that query is completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

$count['open']    = 0;

$count['close']   = 0;

$count['process'] = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {   

    if($row["status"]=='Open') 
    {         
        $count['open']++;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["evaid"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["status"]. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } 
    if($row["status"]=='Close') 
    {  // I want to count this value as 2        
    $count['close']++;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["evaid"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["status"]. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    } 
if($row["status"]=='Process') 
{  // I want to count this value as 2        
    $count['process']++;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["evaid"]. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["status"]. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

}


print_r($count);

?>
```

Comment: the array will have the contents of each record. print_r($count);

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - when i print this value print_r($count); --- it's show result  as Array ( [open] => 3 [close] => 7 [process] => 15 ) , can you please help to extract only the value as 3 7 15.

Comment: hi, echo $count['open'] (show result is 3); echo  $count['close'] (show result is 7) ; echo  $count['process'] (show result is 15) (access array content)

Answer (score 1):

// Hii.. You can get a count from your SQL query itself, try this

```
$sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(ID) AS COUNT FROM (SELECT * FROM disagreements ORDER BY addeddate DESC) disagreements  GROUP BY evaid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{ 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {   
        if($row["status"]=='Open')   
        {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['count'] . "</td>"; // here you will get a count
           echo "<td>" . $row["evaid"]. "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row["status"]. "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
        }
      } 
    } 
 else 
{
    echo "Nothing to Display";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```